# Questions about equivalence hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-signed-rank, equivalence

The setup for the current question is the same as [a previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/639275/300849) of mine, with one important difference: I have decided to go for a paired test, by always performing two consecutive experiments with the two possible inputs (zero or random), although I randomize the order (zeros first and random second, or vice-versa) for each measurement, seeking to avoid certain domain-specific biases (if anyone cares, related to the out-of-order execution capability of the underlying CPU).

After more research into the issue, I've learned about [equivalence tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test), and the more I read about them, the more I'm convinced they're the correct approach for my problem. Not only it answers the "correct" question, but I believe it sidesteps an issue described on that question, of having too many samples, so that a test would reject the null hypothesis by identifying a difference that is too small to be relevant to my problem at hand.

In particular I've come across the [`EQUIVNONINF` R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EQUIVNONINF/EQUIVNONINF.pdf) and have been reading its documentation, as well as the associated monograph "Testing Statistical Hypotheses of Equivalence and Noninferiority" by Stefan Wellek.

Given the particulars of my data set (paired, non-normal, discrete [integer, actually] data with high probability of ties), I believe the `srktie` functions, which perform a signed rank equivalence test generalized for discrete data, are most appropriate for my problem. In particular, the `srktie_m`, which is said to be faster, is applicable, so that's the one I planned to go with. This leads to my first question:

**Question 1: is the `srktie_m` really the "best" choice in my case?**

I understand that I need to define, prior to running the tests, the equivalence interval in my case, and that it is something that needs to be answered by domain-specific knowledge. I have decided that any differences below one clock cycle must be attributable to measurement noise, since a CPU is a digital electronic circuit which operates in quantums of clock cycles.

I believe the equivalence interval is related to the `eps1` and `eps2` parameters to the `srktie_m` function. They are defined as left-hand and right-hand limits of the hypothetical equivalence range for $q_+/(1 − q_0) − 1/2$, where $q_+ = P[D_i + D_j > 0]$ and $q_0 = P[D_i + D_j = 0]$, where, as I understand, $D_i$ and $D_j$ are the differences in clock cycles between a "zeros" input and a "random" input for two randomly selected measurements. I am unsure how to relate this to my 1 clock cycle equivalence hypothesis (I feel it has to do with the variance of the distribution somehow), which leads me to my second question:

**Question 2: how do I choose `eps1` and `eps2` in `srktie_m` so that differences of less than one clock cycle are considered equivalent?**

As I'm looking to run this test by the book, I would like to perform a power analysis first, to determine the required sample size before actually running the test. Note that these are computer experiments, for which I can easily perform a million measurements, and perhaps even a billion wouldn't be out of the question, but I have no idea if a million samples is too little or enough; or if a billion samples is too much (or worse, still too little). I understand it would be "cheating" to simply rerun the tests with more samples if I got a "non-equivalent" response.

Although I can find some functions that appear suitable for power calculation for other tests in the `EQUIVNONINF` package, I can't seem to find one for the `srktie` functions. Skimming through Wellek's monograph, I also haven't found anything about this. Which leads to my third question:

**Question 3: how to calculate power and sample size for the signed-rank with ties equivalence test?**

Lastly, I'm trying to understand if I should apply the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction), given that I have (as stated in my previous question) an ensemble composed of different parameter sets (security levels for the underlying cryptographic algorithm), implementations and other parameters.

Although these are not multiple comparisons within the same data set (as each parameter generates a different set of measurements), ultimately the research question that I'm trying to answer is "does the hardware display data-independent timing?", and I collect evidence to answer that question through these different parameter sets and implementations. This leads me to the fourth and final question:

**Question 4: would it be proper to apply the Bonferroni correction to my ensemble of measurements?**

Answer (score 1):

These are quite a few questions. Maybe I can focus on addressing the third one. However, you may need to tailor it to suit your specific situation. The pwrss R package effectively manages power for equivalence tests for both independent and dependent groups, although grasping its functionality solely from the documentation can be challenging. It took me some time to understand.

To begin, you'll need to establish a minimal effect size to define the bounds for equivalence. How much disparity can you accept? It could be simpler to articulate this value in terms of Cohen's d (at least in social science).

```
library(pwrss)

# Cohen's d = 0.25 - 0.25 = 0 for a paired sample
# need not be 0.25 - 0.25, can be 0.50 - 0.50 or even 0 - 0
np.desing <- pwrss.np.2groups(mu1 = 0.25, mu2 = 0.25, margin = 0.10, 
                              paired = TRUE, power = 0.80, 
                              alternative = "equivalent")

# Non-parametric Difference between Two Groups (Dependent samples) 
# Wilcoxon signed-rank Test for Matched Pairs 
# Method: GUENTHER 
# ------------------------------ 
#  Statistical power = 0.8 
#  n = 899 
# ------------------------------ 
# Alternative = “equivalent” 
# Non-centrality parameter = -2.929 
# Degrees of freedom = 856.74 
# Type I error rate = 0.05 
# Type II error rate = 0.2
```

For what exactly do we need a minimum of 899 observations? Let's try to make sense of effect size margins in terms of probability of superiority.

````
# probability of superiority for d = 0 under equivalence 
np.desing$parms$prob1

# [1] 0.5

# tolerance for probability of superiority under equivalence 
delta <- np.desing$parms$prob1margin - np.desing$parms$prob1

# lower bound for probability of superiority 
lb.margin <- np.desing$parms$prob1 - delta

# upper bound for probability of superiority 
ub.margin <- np.desing$parms$prob1 + delta 

# equivalence bounds for probability of superiority 
round(c(lb.margin, ub.margin), 2)

# [1] 0.47 0.53

```
````